# Angularjs ng-repeat does not update after changing $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am new to Angularjs. I am changing the $scope variable on dropdown list selection. that scope variable is used for ng-repeat on div.

html code:

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="model in FilteredModels | filter:{ModelText : '!All models'}:true">
          <div class="well">
            <div class="media">
              <div class="media-object small"><i class="pp-car"></i></div>
              <div class="media-body">  
                <div class="text-box">                                      
                  <h3>{{model.ModelText}}</h3><span class="hr-small"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="dashboard-control clearfix">
                  <div class="simple-metric text-left sub-metric">
                    <div class="metric-title">Satisfaction score</div>
                    <div class="metric-number text-red">{{model.SatisfactionAvg | number:2}}</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="simple-metric text-left sub-metric">
                    <div class="metric-title">Total interviews</div>
                    <div class="metric-number">{{model.TotalInterviews}}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-standard">
                  <li> <a href="" ng-click="openModal($index)" class="text-black trigger-model-interviews">View interviews</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

angularjs code :

```
function filtermodelbyId() {
    $scope.FilteredModels = [];

    dataFactory.getModelIdByFilter($scope.region, $scope.subregion).success($scope.handleSuccess).then(function (result) {
        $scope.FilteredModelIds = result.data;
    });

    if ($scope.FilteredModelIds != null && $scope.FilteredModelIds.length > 0) {
        for (var j = $scope.FilteredModelIds.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            for (var i = $scope.models.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if ($scope.models[i].ModelId == $scope.FilteredModelIds[j]) {
                    $scope.FilteredModels.push($scope.models[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On change of dropdown list this filtermodelbyId() function gets call and i am pushing new values but this gets reflected after the second change on dropdown list.

is there any better way to represent this.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are not using `$http` in `dataFactory.getModelIdByFilter` .
try using

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
  $scope.FilteredModelIds = result.data;
});
```

Or else you can use angular services to load data (Assuming that you are using jquery ajax.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to write if after `$scope.FilteredModelIds` is set

```
dataFactory.getModelIdByFilter($scope.region, $scope.subregion).success($scope.handleSuccess).then(function (result) {
    $scope.FilteredModelIds = result.data;
    if ($scope.FilteredModelIds != null && $scope.FilteredModelIds.length > 0) {
        for (var j = $scope.FilteredModelIds.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            for (var i = $scope.models.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if ($scope.models[i].ModelId == $scope.FilteredModelIds[j]) {
                    $scope.FilteredModels.push($scope.models[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just of quick wild guess:

```
function filtermodelbyId() {
    $scope.FilteredModels = [];

    dataFactory.getModelIdByFilter($scope.region, $scope.subregion).success($scope.handleSuccess).then(function (result) {
        $scope.FilteredModelIds = result.data;

        if ($scope.FilteredModelIds != null && $scope.FilteredModelIds.length > 0) {
            for (var j = $scope.FilteredModelIds.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                for (var i = $scope.models.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if ($scope.models[i].ModelId == $scope.FilteredModelIds[j]) {
                    $scope.FilteredModels.push($scope.models[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Change the model array in the callback.

Comment: That's what issue is the array doesnt set on callback so i am getting response of previous select.